# Please explain the different types of Context in YAML with proper examples

Tags: yaml

YAML contains six different types of Contexts.
Block-in, Block-out, Flow-in, Flow-out, Block-key, Flow-key.
I get the difference between Block-key and Flow-key but I am not able
differentiate between the other four contexts.

I have seen quite a few examples and their definition in YAML specs but I am not able to differentiate between them properly.
So, please show the differences between them with some examples and also explain when does one context convert into another context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a short description of the six different contexts under [Production parameters](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2769866)

## block-in

```
---
- foo
```

Each value of a block sequence is in block-in context.

Additionally, top-level nodes are also in block-in context, although you can only derive that from production 207 and not from the short description of contexts.

## block-out

```
---
key:
- foo
```

A value of a block mapping is in block-out context. This is important for indentation, so this is why you can "zero-indent" such a sequence (or why dashes "count" as indentation).

Here is the production that defines that difference:
https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#seq-spaces(n,c)

```
[201]   seq-spaces(n,c) ::= c = block-out ⇒ n-1
                            c = block-in  ⇒ n
```

## block-key

```
---
foo: bar
```

Keys in a block mapping are in block-key context.

## flow-key

```
---
{ foo: bar }
```

Keys in a flow mapping are in flow-key context.

## flow-in

```
---
{ key: foo }
---
[ foo ]
```

Values in flow collections are in flow-in context.

## flow-out

```
---
- foo
```

Values outside flow collections are in flow-out context.

---

It might seem that contexts can overlap, and I agree that it's not very well explained in the spec. Details make only sense if you explain each production.

I guess it also depends what you need this for. If you are implementing a parser then it will probably all make more sense when you understand and implement the single productions.

Be sure to use the [YAML Test Suite](https://github.com/yaml/yaml-test-suite) when implementing a parser, and join us on freenode IRC in #yaml-dev.